# How to get value from object - React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this very basic piece of code. I can click on the map and it shows the marker with certain coordinates. Works perfect. `onMapClick` sets `markerPosition` to the latitute and longitude (works fine)

But now I want to show the coordinates in the HTML. I tried `Coordinates are {this.props.markerPosition}` but `this.props.markerPosition` is always null. How can I get the value of markerPosition?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withStateHandlers } from "recompose";
import { InfoWindow, withGoogleMap, withScriptjs, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';


const Map = compose(
    withStateHandlers(() => ({
        isMarkerShown: false,
        markerPosition: null
      }), {
        onMapClick: ({ isMarkerShown }) => (e) => ({
            markerPosition: e.latLng,
            isMarkerShown:true
        })
      }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)
    (props =>
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={8}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
            onClick={props.onMapClick}
        >
            {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={props.markerPosition} />}

        </GoogleMap>
    )

export default class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                <Map
                    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAvcDy5ZYc2ujCS6TTtI3RYX5QmuoV8Ffw"
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                />

                Coordinates are {this.props.markerPosition}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-snxake

Comment: The methods getPosition().ab and getPosition().cb ??? Show these docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Comment: @Liuk it's almost the same issue. How can I access the marker created outside the class?

Comment: But you didn't pass any props to `<MapContainer />`?

Comment: You haven't passed anything to props, so in MapContainer component props will be null.